# Is it possible to import all GA data to big query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am having GA data which is tracking the web information. But currently if I import from GA to big query, it is importing from the day I initiated the GA-Big query linking. Is it possible to import all the data from the beginning to big query ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible and there are few ways for achieving that. Please refer to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en) for more info.